# How can i access my localhost XAMP server from my Android mobile?

Tags: android, localhost

When i run my project on Emulator than localhost  servery is working but when run on real Android phone than localhost server not found. So how can i access my localhost server from my real Android Device. I use XAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access localhost from your mobile device because the server is limited to your system only. In order to test the application you have to run the application on emulator so that it could find the server. Although there is a way...if you are creating a whole server that is backend and you have a network to which your mobile and system is connected then you can set your server to listen to a port on that network. I used NodeJs to accomplish that. You can search some tutorials for using NodeJs  through which you can access you xampp server. You can also try AdonisJs which is a framework for NodeJs for a better approach. But keep in mind that you need a common network through which your system and your mobile device is connected. It is a bit complicated method but yes that can work. Accessing localhost directly from system to your mobile device is not possible..if you want to avoid learning NodeJs then you'll have to keep using emulator for the testing but learning something new is always amazing. So i would suggest you to learn NodeJs . Anyways you can avoid all the trouble and keep testing your application using your emulator. I hope this answer will help you :)

Comment: What a big nonsense!

Comment: Pardon me if something was wrong in my answer as i am not much experienced but the approach that i told above helped me in achieving the same result. I also agree to your answer as yeah if the client and server are connected to the same network then it is possible to access localhost with ip's which i also mentioned above but with different approach. Again pardon me if anything was wrong in my answer. I am just new here.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Please upvote the answer if it satisfies you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have told which ip you used running on emulator.

Your client on the android device should use the ip of the computer where your server is running on.

Android device and server computer in same WLAN.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer and mobile are connected through same internet line then you can use ip of your computer instead of localhost can do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the local host server from a different node eventhough both nodes are connected to same network only way is that change the ip configuration of server to 0.0.0.0: so that you can access the server from any node just by typing the ip of the server followed by port no...